# How to remove selected special character from list

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have C# list where lot of values like this

`<b>Moon</b>`

and i want to remove `<b>` and `</b>`.

I want result like this `Moon`.

How can i remove this type of characters from list.

Comment: Your post appears to have been mangled by the formatting code, hard to tell what you started with...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `XDocument` to remove the XML tags:

```
string StripXmlTags(string xml)
{
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
    return doc.Root.Value;
}
```

Example:

```
[Test]
public void Test()
{
    string xml = "<root><b>nice </b><c>node</c><d><e> is here</e></d></root>";
    string result = StripXmlTags(xml);

    Assert.AreEqual("nice node is here", result);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var moonHtml = "<b>Moon</b>";
var regex = new Regex("</?(.*)>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);
var moon = regex.Replace(moonHtml, string.Empty);
```

Comment: 12 secs faster, what a shame ;)

Comment: Why specify "zero or one /" `/?` when the slash would've been included in the dot that follows? Why specify ignore-case when there are no alphabetic characters? Best practice? Oh well. Your code is greedy. If there's a string like `abc <b>Moon</b> more text <b>more moon</b>` then you'll just end up with "abc ".

Comment: DO NOT use regex to parse html - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Regex.Replace("<b>Moon</b>", @"\<.+?\>", "")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string noHtml = Regex.Replace(inputWithHtmlTags, "<[^>]+>", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

This program is a very crude illustration of a regex that will remove all tags, it's flexible enough to also remove italic and underlines. It use the IgnoreCase option to guard against `<b>`or `<B>` being in the input and will carry out the search over multiple lines. The output from running this will be "The Man on the Moon". I use .*? meaning zero or more to catch cases of empty brackets such as `<>`

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program
    {
       static void Main(string[] args)
       {
           var input = "<b>The</b> <i>Man</i> on the <U><B>Moon</B></U>";

           var regex = new Regex("<.*?>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);

           var output = regex.Replace(input, string.Empty);

           Console.WriteLine(output);
           Console.ReadLine();
      }
    }
```

}